# Limit number of program executions

Tags: executable, limit

Please help me to find out how to limit number of program concurrent executions. I mean, particular program can be ran only, for example 5 times at once. I know how to limit proccess number for user, but how to do that for program, using PAM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PAM is used to authorize logins and account modifications. It is not at all relevant to restricting a specific program.

The only way to apply a limit to the number of times a program can be executed is to invoke it through a wrapper that applies this limit. Users can of course bypass this wrapper by having their own copy of the program; if you don't want that, don't give those users account on your machine.

To restrict a program to a single instance, you can make it take an exclusive lock on a file. There's no straightforward way to use a file to allow a limited number of instances, but you can use 5 files to allow 5 instances, and make the wrapper script try each file in turn. Create a directory `/var/lib/myapp/instances` (or wherever you want to put it) and create 5 files in it, all world-readable but only writable by root.

```
umask 022
mkdir /var/lib/myapp
touch /var/lib/myapp/instances/{1,2,3,4,5}
```

Wrapper script (replace `myapp.original` by the path to the original executable), using Linux's [`flock`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html) utility:

```
#!/bin/sh
for instance in /var/lib/myapp/instances/*; do
  flock -w 0 -E 128 "$instance" myapp.original "$@"
  ret=$?
  if [ "$ret" -ne 128 ]; then exit "$ret"; fi
done
echo >&2 "Maximum number of instances of myapp reached."
exit 128
```

Comment: Brilliant hack. I like what feels like a slight misuse of flock, and creating files to tune how many instances can run.  Nice bit of scripting!