# How to add file markers to check if script is already running

Tags: bash, rsync, synology, wait

I wonder if I can get some help with a project I'm working on. I have a Synology NAS. I found a Community Package that autoruns a script of my creation anytime a USB drive is plugged in to one of the drives. My script copies images and movie files to a given folder from all USB drives/Sandisk cards listed in the script into a specific folder on the Synology. The autorun package runs the script **every** time each drive is plugged in. The problem is if I plug in four USB drives one after the other within 15 seconds, it copies all four drives four times. Instead I want it wait 15 seconds to allow me to plug in all USBs, and then copy all drives once.

My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
var=$(date +"%FORMAT_STRING")
now=$(date +”%m_%d_%Y_%s”)
printf "%s\n" $now
today=$(date +%m-%d-%Y-%s)
rsync -avz --prune-empty-dirs --include "*/" --include="*."{cr2,CR2,mov,MOV,mpg,MPG,dng,DNG,jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG} --exclude="*" /volumeUSB1/usbshare/ /volume1/KingstonSSD/Camera_Loads/Sandisk-${today}
rsync -avz --prune-empty-dirs --include "*/" --include="*."{cr2,CR2,mov,MOV,mpg,MPG,dng,DNG,jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG} --exclude="*" /volumeUSB2/usbshare/ /volume1/KingstonSSD/Camera_Loads/Sandisk-${today}
rsync -avz --prune-empty-dirs --include "*/" --include="*."{cr2,CR2,mov,MOV,mpg,MPG,dng,DNG,jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG} --exclude="*" /volumeUSB3/usbshare/ /volume1/KingstonSSD/Camera_Loads/Sandisk-${today}
rsync -avz --prune-empty-dirs --include "*/" --include="*."{cr2,CR2,mov,MOV,mpg,MPG,dng,DNG,jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG} --exclude="*" /volumeUSB4/usbshare4-2/ /volume1/KingstonSSD/Camera_Loads/Sandisk-${today}
```

My goal is to have the script wait a given time (say 15 seconds), to allow me to plug in all four USBs. Then after 15 seconds, run the code one time. I guess I need to check if the code is already running for any of the USBs plugged in. Terminate the current script if so, copy files if not.

I found this, I'm wondering if I can tweak it and add it to mine to check if any other instances of my script are running and terminate if so... or copy files if not:

```
if [ `ps -ef | grep "script.sh" | grep -v grep | wc -l` -gt 1 ] ; then
echo "RUNNING...."
else
echo "NOT RUNNING..."
fi
```

Any chance anyone would help with a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like a definite bug in the "Community Package". IIWY, I'd be reluctant to depend on a package that behaves this way. Full disclosure: I've had some issues with Synology's tech support; i.e. my skepticism is triggered when I hear the term "Synology"  :)

Comment: This [other Q&A here in U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/337641/286615) may be a reasonable solution in your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote

```
today=$(date +%m-%d-%Y-%s)
...
```

It appears the answer could be as simple as

```
today=$(date +%m-%d-%Y-%s)
sleep 15
...
```

---

Consider putting those `rsync`s inside a bash function named `sync_all`.

Then you could run everything twice -- immediately, and after a delay.

```
sync_all
sleep 15
sync_all
```

The cool thing about `rsync` is it is "mostly free" to
run it multiple times, since it will notice if a file
has already been copied.

---

You don't *need* to coordinate among rsync's.
Suppose a pair of rsync processes are simultaneously
trying to copy a giant ReadMe file from /here to /there.
Do they both open /there/ReadMe ? No !
Instead they invent a new random filename like /there/.123
or /there/.456, copy into *that*, and at the end
do an atomic `rename()` to `mv` the numeric filename to /there/ReadMe.
They're both good copies, so it doesn't matter which one wins.
There will be no file truncation or corruption,
just a few more writes hitting the disk than absolutely necessary.

---

Certainly you can exclude other competing instances, if you like.
The c-news [shlock](https://linux.die.net/man/1/shlock)
utility is a convenient way to do so.
The first script to run will write a lock file
which says "keep out!", and subsequent scripts
will notice it and immediately exit, before
attempting to do any work.

Asking `ps` "am I already running?" will give you a *hint*
about existing background processes. But using a proper
locking primitive will *guarantee* that at most a single
participant is within the critical section at any instant.
The `ps` approach will always be somewhat racy.

Comment: Thank you so much for the informative reply! I was able to see the random filename happening. I did end up removing the ``$today`` variable, as that was definitely creating new folders for each insertion of USB. I ended up removing that. The result was rsync performed just as you said, leaving one good copy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your approach is correct. The "event" is when all 4 drives are mounted, not after 15 seconds.

You could revise your script to exit if all 4 drives aren't mounted ....

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# test if a drive is mounted ..
mountp() { findmnt ${MNTPT} >/dev/null }

if  mountp volumeUSB1 && mountp volumeUSB2 && mountp volumeUSB3 && mountp volumeUSB4 ; then
    var=$(date +"%FORMAT_STRING")
    now=$(date +”%m_%d_%Y_%s”)
    printf "%s\n" $now
    today=$(date +%m-%d-%Y-%s)
    rsync -avz --prune-empty-dirs --include "*/" --include="*."{cr2,CR2,mov,MOV,mpg,MPG,dng,DNG,jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG} --exclude="*" /volumeUSB1/usbshare/ /volume1/KingstonSSD/Camera_Loads/Sandisk-${today}
    rsync -avz --prune-empty-dirs --include "*/" --include="*."{cr2,CR2,mov,MOV,mpg,MPG,dng,DNG,jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG} --exclude="*" /volumeUSB2/usbshare/ /volume1/KingstonSSD/Camera_Loads/Sandisk-${today}
    rsync -avz --prune-empty-dirs --include "*/" --include="*."{cr2,CR2,mov,MOV,mpg,MPG,dng,DNG,jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG} --exclude="*" /volumeUSB3/usbshare/ /volume1/KingstonSSD/Camera_Loads/Sandisk-${today}
    rsync -avz --prune-empty-dirs --include "*/" --include="*."{cr2,CR2,mov,MOV,mpg,MPG,dng,DNG,jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG} --exclude="*" /volumeUSB4/usbshare4-2/ /volume1/KingstonSSD/Camera_Loads/Sandisk-${today}
fi
```

Note for above: the script exits unless all four are mounted.